# Create a Azure Analysis Service tabular Model Partition in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-analysis-services

using AMO how we create  azure analysis service  Partition using C# code
with Azure funcation App
Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

You can add partitions just like columns

```
            var ds = myDatabaseObject.Model.DataSources.Find("DW Connection");
            ds.Model.Tables.Add(new Table
            {
                Name = "tablename",
                Columns =
                {
                    new DataColumn
                    {
                        Name = "Id",
                        DataType = DataType.Int64,
                        SourceColumn = "Id",
                        SourceProviderType = "BigInt",
                        IsUnique = true,
                        IsKey = true
                    },
                    new DataColumn
                    {
                        Name = "DateId",
                        DataType = DataType.DateTime,
                        SourceColumn = "DateId",
                        FormatString = "General Date",
                        SourceProviderType = "Date"
                    }
                    [...]
                },
                Partitions =
                {
                    new Partition
                    {
                        Name = "Main",
                        DataView = DataViewType.Full,
                        Source = new QueryPartitionSource
                        {
                            DataSource = ds,
                            Query = query
                        }
                    }
                    [...]
                }
            });
```

Adding or removing partitions is also not a problem. For example this is (more or less) the code i'm using to add partitions with new data

```
        var partitionName = $"name of partition you want to add";
        var newDataPartition = new Partition
        {
            Name = partitionName,
            DataView = DataViewType.Full,
            Source = new QueryPartitionSource
            {
                DataSource = ds,
                Query = "sql query here"
            }
        };

        if (!table.Partitions.ContainsName(partitionName))
        {
            table.Partitions.Add(newDataPartition);
        }
        db.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
        table.Partitions[partitionName].RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
        table.Partitions["Main"].RequestMerge(new List<Partition> { table.Partitions[partitionName] });
        db.Model.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for update now we need to implement using Azure function App

Comment: hi, please share full code with name space it's not work for me

Comment: I can't share full code. Azure analysis services requires dlls that can work with tabular object model compatibility 1200 and higher. Basically you need dlls from SQL server 2016 or higher. Look for Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll, Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.dll and Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.dll.

Comment: Older dlls (version 12.0.* and lower)  will not work with azure at all